# passing pointers to extern C function in a DLL from VB

Tags: c++, vb.net, dll

I am a C++ (MSVC) writer, VB newbie trying to assist an expert VB.net writer who has just not done this task before.

We wish to develop both C/C++ and VB applications to use a DLL written in C++ with C extern-ed API functions.  The C++ program is working just fine.  It's VB where we are having difficulties.

The DLL provides an `extern C` function:

```
RegisterCallback( void* cbFuncPtr, void* dataPtr );
```

**NOTE 1:  See my note below for a design change and the reasons we made it.**

**NOTE 2: Additional update added as an answer below.**

where the callback function havs this C typedef:

```
typedef   (void)(* CALL_NACK)(void*);
```

The `cbFuncPtr` is expected to be a function pointer to some VB function that will get  called as the CALL_BACK.  The `dataPtr` is a pointer to a data structure that has this C definition:

```
typedef struct 
{
   int      retCode;
   void*    a_C_ptr;
   char     message[500];
}  cbResponse_t;
```

where `a_C_ptr is an internal pointer in the DLL that the VB can cast to`long`.  It uniquely identifies where in the DLL the callback was made and allows the VB function to recognize calls from same/different locations.

We are able to access and run the `RegisterCallback()` function from VB just fine.  Logging shows we get there and that data is passed in.  It is the actual data that seems to be the problem.

In reading about a million forum entries we have learned that VB doesn't know what pointers are and that a VB structure is more than just organized memory.  We're pretty sure the "address" of a VB structure is not what C thinks an address is.  We've seen repeated references to "marshaling" and "managed data", but lack enough understanding to know what that is telling us.

How should we code VB to give the DLL the execution address of its callback function and how do we code up a VB construct that the DLL can fill in just as it does for C++?

Might we need a DLL function where the calling app can say "C" or "VB" andhave the DLL handle the sturcture pointers differently?  If so, how would one code up C to fill in the VB structure?

Comment: This [MS article about how to marshall data to a DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzhhdwae.aspx) at least looks like it might apply.  It was linked to by this [article about calling C++ DLLs from VB](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/4c486d10-fe8b-49da-a5f1-8054b82251ff/). I'm not a VB or .NET programmer, so I may be off the mark.

Comment: @DaveNewman The last posting to that discussion is already a big help.  As a C programmer the idea that data could just up and move around and that pointers to it are trusted only for about as long as the statement that queried them, is heresy.   Guess I'll have to create the structure on the DLL side adn tell the app where I put the data.  That defeats the idea of letting the app own the data so that it would be there despite whatever the DLL might do.

Comment: As far as I know, in vb.net it is very useful to prefer the IntPtr structure for pointers. But if you already have a pointer definition, not sure if really needed. Pointer are also available in vb.net, just a bit harder to find

Comment: @Wes Miller Great. I hope those links lead to a successful outcome.

Comment: @Amegon I will pass your note to my VB colleague.  The idea of passing a structure, IntPtr or otherwise sounds great too, but doesn't the DLL interface, at least for C/C++ require that all data and function calls be `extern C` and, therefore, that the only passable datatypes are POD, plain old data?

Comment: @Amegon We seem to be stuck on pointers for the function too.  Could you explain exactly how we should get the address of the callback function so that C will understand it?  Or does C need to parse some structure at the supplied address to find/calculate the callable address?

Comment: Updates added as an answer.  Won't fit in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit too big and deep to just be an edit to the original posting...

From the [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/4c486d10-fe8b-49da-a5f1-8054b82251ff/) posted by @DaveNewman, I extracted this gem:

---

> Here's a bit about the compact framework, but it's the same in the
>   grown-ups framework:
>
> The .NET Compact Framework supports automatic marshaling of structures
>   and classes that contain simple types. All fields are laid out
>   sequentially in memory in the same order as they appear in the
>   structure or class definition. Both classes and structures appear in
>   native code as pointers to C/C++ structs.
>
> Objects in the managed heap can be moved around in memory at any time
>   by the garbage collector, so their physical addresses may change
>   without notice. P/Invoke automatically pins down managed objects
>   passed by reference for the duration of each method call. This means
>   pointers passed to unmanaged code will be valid for that one call.
>   Bear in mind that there is no guarantee that the object will not be
>   moved to a different memory address on subsequent calls.
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446538.aspx#netcfmarshallingtypes_topic6

---

This is major hurdle for a `RegisterCallback( fcnPtr, dataPtr)` function.  The pointer passed in at registration time could change at any time the `RegisterCallback()` is not the current statement.  The posting author summed it up this way

> You don't need to do anything as the structures are pinned automatically for duration of the call.

implying, of course, not pinned down outside the call.

For this reason we decided on a design change to have the response structure built in, so to speak, the C/C++ world of the DLL, not in VB's space.  That way it'll stay put.  The actual callback function's signature will remain unchanged so the VB program can know where the DLL put the response.  This also allows the responders in the DLL to allocate separate response structures for separate needs.

Comment: An update.  Based on @DaveNewman posting and great work by my co-worker, we are adding in the managed to unmanaged classes suggested in [Calling Managed Code from Unmanaged Code and vice-versa](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9903/Calling-Managed-Code-from-Unmanaged-Code-and-vice#xx3493475xx).

Answer (score 0):

Once again my update is too large for a mere comment!

**Update 18 Apr 2013:**

Well, the attempt to use the code from [Calling Managed Code from Unmanaged Code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9903/Calling-Managed-Code-from-Unmanaged-Code-and-vice#xx3493475xx) cited above was a bust.  We ended up having to add /clr to the DLL make turning the DLL into managed code, which made it unusable from a C application.

We are now testing the example at [Callback Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zwkzwf4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3) which I was able to show made a DLL that worked with both VB and C++.  You'd need to have the [PinvokeLib.dll Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as6wyhwt%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to make this work.

Here is the code for the C++ (C really) tester.  Compiled as a MSVC project.

---

NOTE:  Notice the __cdecl in this line:

```
typedef bool (__cdecl *FPtr)(BOOL_FP_INT fp, int i );
```

It was the secret I had to find.  The DLL and this app are compiled with __cdecl linkage, not __stdcall.  They are the default in VC++ and I just used the defaults.  I tried changing everything to __stdcall but that didn't work.  Has to be __cdecl.

---

```
// PinvokeTester.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//


#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <Windows.h>

#define PINVOKELIB_API __declspec(dllimport)

HINSTANCE      hLib;                            // Windows DLL handle

bool     CALLBACK VBCallBack( int value );
bool     AttachLibrary( void );
void *   GetFuncAddress( HINSTANCE hLib, const char* procname );

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   if ( !AttachLibrary() )
   {
      printf( "Lib did not attach.\n" );
      exit(1);
   }

   typedef bool (CALLBACK *BOOL_FP_INT)(int i );

   typedef bool (__cdecl *FPtr)(BOOL_FP_INT fp, int i );

   FPtr TestCallBack = (FPtr)GetFuncAddress( hLib, "TestCallBack" );

   TestCallBack( (BOOL_FP_INT)VBCallBack, 255 );

    return 0;
}

bool CALLBACK VBCallBack( int value )
{
    printf( "\nCallback called with param: %d", value);
    return true;
}


bool     AttachLibrary( void )
{
   // Get a var for the IPC-dll library.
   std::string    dllName;

   /*--- First, link to the IPC-dll library or report failure to do so. ---*/
   dllName = ".\\PinvokeLib";
   if ( NULL == (hLib = LoadLibraryA( dllName.c_str() )) )
   {
      printf( "\nERROR: Library \"%s\" Not Found or Failed to Load. \n\n", dllName.c_str() );
      printf( "\"%s\"\n", GetLastError() );
      return false;
   }

   return true;
}

//=====================================================================
void *  GetFuncAddress( HINSTANCE hLib, const char* procname )
{
   void *   procAddr = NULL;

   procAddr = (void *)GetProcAddress( hLib, procname );

   // If the symbol wasn't found, handle error ---------------------
   if ( NULL == procAddr )
   {
      std::cout << "ERROR: Could not get an address for the \""
                << procname  << "\" function. : "
                << GetLastError()  << std::endl;
      exit( 7 );
      procAddr = (void*)NULL;
   }

   return procAddr;
}
```